# Collecting disjoint like terms in polynomial expressions

Tags: c++, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

This is my first post on here so thanks in advance and bear with me if I do not follow the format guide.

My problem is as follows: I have several polynomial expressions in the variable "s" up to degree 10. Each of the coefficients are then functions of up to 10 other variables. Overall the code for all of the coefficient functions takes up about 800 text-wrapped lines of code with single coefficients having up to 40 lines of code. I  am writing an optimization routine in C++ that tries to determine the optimal values for each of the 10 variables that the coefficients depend on.

Profiling my code, I see that I am spending 78% of my time in this one function. To optimize, I would like to search the whole code and find redundant calculations, compute them at the start of the routine and replace all of their occurrences with the previously calculated expression. The problem is that the most frequently occurring expressions may be something like:

`a0 = ... + R1*R2*G1*R3 + R1*R2*H1*R3 + ...;`

I would like to find a way to search through the lines and sort out the `R1*R2*R3` terms to replace them with something like `X` where `X = R1*R2*R3;` is declared at the start of the code. These regular expressions may occur several hundred times throughout the code, so I am sure that this can drastically improve my run time. Additionally, I can only group things separated by multiplication, not addition.

Basically, I need a replace string function that can find disjoint strings whose member terms are separated by other terms and `*` signs but not `+` signs. This may be a tall order, or incredibly simple, I am really not sure.

I have Mathematica, MATLAB, and Maple available to me and run Debian, so I can download something if it is open source that may be more helpful. I typically use Emacs for my programming, though I am by no means proficient with all of its functionality. I am open to any suggestions, and greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like a preprocessing tool to scan the text of your source code and emit revised source code?

Comment: (By the way, do you have Mathematica, MATLAB and Maple running on *Debian?*  Using Wine?  That's a neat trick.)

Comment: It's possible that your compiler is already doing a certain amount of [*common subexpression elimination*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) by itself.

Comment: I have the linux versions of each running under debian and I am not sure if the compiler is automatically taking care of this. I am using g++ 4.4.3.

Comment: I would not like to emit source code, I would like a similar tool to Emacs M-x replace-string, but where I can search for combinations of terms that may not be contiguous and replace them. ie if something like `a0` described in the opening post has terms R1, R2, and R3 all in the same multiplication many times throughout the expression but not necessarily next to each other, then I can replace that with a single term, say `X`, calculated prior to entering the `a0` expression to save computation time

Comment: Multiple solutions are certainly possible, but if you want to know what I would be inclined to try in your place, I would probably write a Perl script (a) to scan the source for such lines of code as in your example; (b) to parse the lines in the manner you have suggested, reducing each such line logically to a sum of products; (c) to look for and react to repeated terms; and (d) to write revised code back out.  However, this would represent a tedious programming exercise, wouldn't it?  It would probably only be worth it if you had several hundred such lines of code to process.

Comment: My last comment may be obviated by your last comment.  The text-editor trick you suggest would be a neat one.  I like the idea but, regrettably, do not know how to implement it.

Comment: It would certainly be tedious in my eyes, I am not a programmer :/ All of my programming experience has been in a mathematical setting with C++. Unfortunately I do not know Perl, but likely it would be worth it since this one section is around 800 lines and the entire routine takes about 3.5 seconds to run once, 78% of the time in this one group of functions, and I will likely need to run this several hundred thousand times when it is finished. Is there anything I can do with symbolic tools such as Mathematica?

Comment: Make sure you compile your source file with the `-O2` or the `-O3` compiler options. The compiler will probably do what you want, automatically.

Comment: In Mathematica there is a function Experimental`OptimizeExpression[] that will attempt to rewrite using common subexpression elimination.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard core-utils, you can do the following:

```
cat filename.cc | tr " +" "\n\n" | grep "*" | sort | uniq -c
```

In plain English this translates to: read the file, convert all spaces and pluses into new-lines. Next, only keep the lines containing multiplication, sort them, and display unique occurrences with they frequency.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was looking for. I will try it this evening. Thank you

Comment: UPDATE: I tried the method posted by user1202136 and it is what I need. I have not fully implemented the suggestion throughout all of the source, just a test section, but I expect it will significantly speed up the program. In the one small test section, I have already removed about 30,000 redundant computations per run. Thanks so much!